# Gremlin: How to select() multiple vertices into a collection then get the one with the highest property value

Tags: sorting, select, group-by, gremlin

Take a traversal like this:

```
g.V().as('a')......has(name,'test').as('b').....select('a','b')
```

At this point, now I've stored and selected out 'a' and 'b', I want to identify the one with the high property value (e.g. `a.score==2`, `b.score==4`, so choose 'b')

How do I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's easier if you give every candidate on the path the same label:

```
g.V().as('a')....
  has('name,'test').as('a').
  select(all, 'a').
  order(local).
    by('score', decr).
  limit(local, 1)
```

Here's how it looks on the modern toy graph:

```
gremlin> g = TinkerFactory.createModern().traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6], standard]
gremlin> g.V().as('a').out('knows').as('a').select(all, 'a')
==>[v[1],v[2]]
==>[v[1],v[4]]
gremlin> g.V().as('a').out('knows').as('a').
......1>   select(all, 'a').
......2>     by(unfold().valueMap(true).fold())
==>[[label:person,name:[marko],age:[29],id:1],[label:person,name:[vadas],age:[27],id:2]]
==>[[label:person,name:[marko],age:[29],id:1],[label:person,name:[josh],age:[32],id:4]]
```

At this point we know that the expected result is `v[1]` (29 > 27) for the first path and `v[4]` (32 > 29) for the second path.

```
gremlin> g.V().as('a').out('knows').as('a').
......1>   select(all, 'a').
......2>   order(local).
......3>     by('age', decr).
......4>   limit(local, 1)
==>v[1]
==>v[4]
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Looks really promising. Hope to try but I just cannot find a way of doing `select(all, 'a')` in gremlin-python, which is what I'm using.

Comment: Did you import statics (`from gremlin_python import statics`)? Also, I believe it's `all_` in Python.

Comment: I just found it myself actually with this:

`from gremlin_python.process.traversal import Pop
....select(Pop.all_,'a')`

But yes importing `statics` would be better.

Comment: With the statics imported everything works up to the `.select(all_,'a')` - but adding any/all the rest of the steps gives me `gremlin_python.driver.protocol.GremlinServerError: 500: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable`

Comment: Turns out that field was (wrongly) a singleton list in the DB. Fixed that and this works now. Thanks!!